# The field must be an accumulator object

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I just read about aggregation in mongoose and it seems pretty useful method and I just tested things on my own, So this is my data in database:

```
[
  {
    product: "chanchuris arayi",
    myidveli: "lg",
    pasi: 12
  },
  {
    product: "kalbasi",
    myidveli: "maiko",
    pasi: 10
  },
  {
    product: "chanchuris arayi",
    myidveli: "zaza",
    pasi: 12
  },
  {
    product: "sulguni",
    myidveli: "shotiko",
    pasi: 7
  },
  {
    product: "kalbasi",
    myidveli: "lg",
    pasi: 10
  }
]
```

and this is my code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      product: "$product",
      pasi: {
        "$sum": "$pasi"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

and it gives me error : **The field must be an accumulator object**, when I type $product in _id field it works as I want but not way, so I got confused can anyone explain me how aggregation is working and what is problem with my code?

Thank you!

Comment: Ok couple of things, 1) Aggregation is mongoDB native(it's a pipeline that can hold chain of stages each stage process the data and final stage is kind of output), though you might have read it in mongoose that's ok. 2) $match does work like .find() , if you don't have anything to filter then no need of it. 3) When you're grouping on '_id' where is that in you sample data & you cannot do group on product like that as it's a field in many objects of an array - Can you please provide entire document & desired output !!

Comment: only thing i wanted to know is that why i must group on _id and not any other field

Comment: you can group on any field and on combination of fields as well, but not like that on a field which is in array, if you can provide entire document and desired o/p I can help you with query..

Answer (score 1):

I hope this the query you're looking for:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [{ 
$unwind: {  path: "$test"} }, {
$group: {  "_id": "$test.product",  
"pasi": { $sum: "$test.pasi"  }} }] )
```